# CRM 2011 (rollup 12) shows the mobile view instead of the normal view in non IE browsers

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I recently went to do a demo of some a CRM solution I had been developing but when I tried displaying it on my MAC in firefox and chrome it comes up with the mobile interface. The instance will never be used on mobile devices so I want to disable this functionality for the whole site...How do I do this?

Comment: I think the settings can be configured per entity.  I'll see if there is some global setting. FYI: http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/08/26/mobile-express-with-crm-2011/

Comment: I saw the per entity setting...that looks like a bunch of work. I was hoping for a checkbox somewhere.

Comment: What rollup are you on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue when I opened crm on firefox (on explorer and chrome it was ok), I assume you are using roll up 12 since only from this rollup you have other browsers besides internet explorer integration.

The issue with me was that for some reason, it opened the "default.aspx" page, which opened this url:

```
https://mydomain:444/m/default.aspx
```

When the correct address should be:

```
https://mydomain:444/main.aspx#
```

I'm also guessing that you have set up ADFS..

Comment: Yes we have adfs and we are using roll up 12

Comment: I think I need to change the question now?

Comment: This resolved the issue for me on Mac OSX 10.11 - Google Chrome, v50. 
I replaced `/m/default.aspx` with `/main.aspx#`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and what helped for me was to add the site to the Compatibility View in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE 11, try compatibility mode. Settings -> Compatibility View Settings